# use css properties as base url for assets

Tags: css, sass

Currently I have this code (**working fine**):

```
$RESOURCE_URL: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload';

background-image: url('#{$RESOURCE_URL}/abc.jpg');
```

Now, I am planning to differentiate the `RESOURCE_URL` based on a variable from backend.
I know that scss variables are just a syntactic sugar and they won't exist at runtime. So, I want to replace it with css custom property so that I can change its value at runtime.

Here is the new code with css custom property (**not-working**):

```
--resource-url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload';

background-image: url('#{var(--resource-url)}/abc.jpg');
```

But this is not working. It gives me a compile time error:

```
Can't resolve './var(--resource-url)/abc.jpg'
```

Comment: you cannot do this with CSS variables

Comment: @TemaniAfif is there any other way?

Comment: not with CSS, you will need JS

Comment: @TemaniAfif so for each resource, I will need to use JS? or can I have any other common solution for that?

Comment: The linked question as duplicate does not answer my particular question. Anyone who has marked it as duplicate, I would like to say that other question is suggesting to use a static URL, but my URL is dynamically constructed.

Comment: *I would like to say that other question is suggesting to use a static URL, but my URL is dynamically constructed.* --> even a static URL won't work with CSS variables so imagine the case with dynamic one.